# Regarding .Net Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, .net-runtime

If my Project A has a reference to a package like NLog 2.0 and Project B, and if Project B also has a reference to NLog 1.0, then at runtime, when Project A executes Project B's functionality, will it use NLog 1.0 or NLog 2.0?

If I upgrade NLog to version 3.0 in Project B, it generates some config settings like dependentAssembly, bindingRedirection in `app.config`. Should I manually add those entries in Project A's `app.config` too?

Please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency resolution is done with either

- 1. PackageReference or
- 2. packages.config

the first is newer and preferred and default in new projects, you should consider to change to it!

then the answer is clear:

"Direct dependency wins"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution